# Getting Error while calling a block `$_product->$_call()`

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, magento2.2.6, php-7

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Method name must be a string in
>   D:\xampp-7.1.23\htdocs\indiahicks\app\design\frontend\Mgs\ethan\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\form.phtml:19

```
<?php 
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); 
    $_product = $block->getProduct();

    $_call = $block->getAtCall();
    $_code = $block->getAtCode();
    $_className = $block->getCssClass();
    $_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
    $_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
    $_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
    $themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data');

    if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
        $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
    }
    if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
        $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
    } else {
        $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the return value of $_call = $block->getAtCall();?

Comment: not getting anything. Actually I copy this code from attribute.phtml and using same code in form.phtml, code is working fine in attribute.phtml but not in form.phtml
I want to dynamic the product detail description. right now it's static

Answer (score 1):

If you open the following file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Then you can see following code:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Where pass **at_call** as **getSku**. So you need to do that too.
When you check in phtml

```
$_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
```

Where **$_product->$_call()** this actually **$_product->getSku()**.

In your case **$_call()** is null.

Answer (score 0):

Create a catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info">
        <arguments>
           <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
           <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
           <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
           <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
           <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
           <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
      </arguments>
  </referenceBlock>
```